# Android android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

Need some help. I use default android Navigation Drawer Activity.
At first build it runs very well. But when i try to change the styles (i want to make it become material design). it gives me this error:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fragment/com.fragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at com.fragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
```

Here is my styles.xml:

```
<resource>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

   <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   </style>
</resource>
```

and i got styles v21:

```
<resources>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

I've tried change at activity_main.xml this from:

```
android:name="com.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
```

to

```
class="com.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout        
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    class="com.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

but still no luck. I still very new at this stuff. I haven't change any code elsewhere since first run.

Comment: post your activity_main.xml as well after you made change.

Comment: @Sharj Hi. I add my activity_main.xml

Comment: You posted your Java class not XML layout.

Comment: @Sharj my bad. i've changed it. thanks

Comment: post the next several lines of the InflateException

Comment: hi @petey. I've update the error several lines of inflate exception